# App appears in task switcher more than once

Tags: android, android-activity, android-applicationinfo

I am developing my first app now and I see that whenever I click on a new activity it opens up and everything is fine. I can also go back to the main activity and then open a different and it all works.

However once I open the task switcher, all the previous activities show up. They all show up as seperate apps and if I click on one of them that is not the main activity I cannot go back the to the main activity its like its very own up with just that activity.

This is very strange. Does this have to do with how I implement the `onDestory` method? Because to be quite frank I never used it.

Please help me!

Thank you!

Comment: How do you launch your activities? Do you have any non-default values for launchMode, documentLaunchMode or taskAffinity? See here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: Thanks, I didnt quite understand the differences between al 4 but I call the new activity using 'new Intent(MainActivity.this, className);' for whatever activity is being called

Comment: How does your manifest look like? I think we need to see more code here with details on how you start the activities (do you add any flags .. etc)

Comment: And they're quite confusing, I think this could help shed some lights: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: hey, this is what I found in the manifest file            
 android:launchMode="singleInstance" I hope this helps, if you need more code, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: That's exactly the reason, if you leave it to the default then you would allow your activities to start in the same task

Comment: Ok thanks, and what would the default be? or should I just erase it completely? Also, I think the reason i put that in the first place was because when you clicked the activity twice, it would open the activity twice. Which was an issue